# How to use the database mongodb on octobercms?

Tags: database, laravel, mongodb, octobercms, migrate

I'm working on a project using **OctoberCMS** and for the database I want to use **MongoDB**. but i have problem while migrating. when the migrate collection fails.
please help so i can solve the problem.
thank you.

**config/database.php**
[config/database.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0fLl.png)

**config/app.php**
[config/app.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwdUI.png)

**.env**
[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Slj.png)

**php artisan october:migrate**
[php artisan october:migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOIOv.png)

Comment: can you please share what kind of error or issue you are facing or screenshots, it will help community to understand issue and answer it fast

Comment: @HardikSatasiya there is no error but I've uploaded an image to help the community understand the problem I'm getting.
thank you.

Comment: MongoDB is not supported by Laravel: "Currently Laravel supports four database systems: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, and SQL Server." Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database

Comment: @MaartenDev I use the jenssegers/mongodb package to support mongodb on laravel

Comment: @MaartenDev That's inaccurate. Laravel provides 'first-party' support to 5 databases. Your comment would imply other databases won't work with Laravel.